# VisualState storyboard not activating on path 'MouseOver' state

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm trying to change the colour of a Path control on mouseover where the path data is always changing through a data binding.  It should change from yellow to red, but There is no colour change on the path as I move my mouse over it, it remains yellow.

**my view:**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow
    x:Class="TestWpfAnim.MainWindow"
    x:TypeArguments="local:MainViewModel"

    xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfAnim"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>

    <local:PointsToPathNormalConv x:Key="MyConv" />


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <!--Take one half second to transition to the MouseOver state.-->
                    <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Path 
        x:Name="MainPath" StrokeThickness="4"
        Data="{Binding Poly, Converter={StaticResource MyConv}}">
        <Path.Stroke>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" x:Name="MyAnimatedBrush" />
        </Path.Stroke>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = ViewModel;

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };
        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;

        timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
        {
            ViewModel.Add(x++, y++ * 2);
        };

        timer.Start();


    }
}
```

**The converter**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<System.Windows.Point>), typeof(Geometry))]
public class PointsToPathNormalConv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable<System.Windows.Point> points && points.Any())
        {
            List<LineSegment> segments = new List<LineSegment>();

            foreach (var p in points)
            {
                segments.Add(new LineSegment(p, true));
            }

            PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(points.First(), segments, false); //true if closed
            PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
            geometry.Figures.Add(figure);

            return geometry;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**my viewmodel:**
**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : AbstractNotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Poly = new ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point>();
    }

    public void Add(int x, int y)
    {
        var newlist = Poly.ToList();
        newlist.Add(new System.Windows.Point(x, y));
        Poly = new ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point>(newlist);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    private ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point> _poly;

    public ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Point> Poly
    {
        get => _poly;
        set => this.SetAndRaise(ref _poly, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see my mistake was making assumptions on pre-existing visual state names based on various sources from which I had first learned about using the VisualStateManager.

Adding the following code to my View functioned as expected:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public void Path_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement fe)
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(fe, "MouseEnter", true);
    }

    public void Path_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is FrameworkElement fe)
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(fe, "MouseLeave", true);
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

Move state manager code into the *Path* element. Specify *MouseEnter* and *MouseLeave* actions on the path which will change the state.

```
<Path 
    x:Name="MainPath" StrokeThickness="4"
    Data="{Binding Poly, Converter={StaticResource MyConv}}" 
    MouseEnter="Path_MouseEnter" 
    MouseLeave="Path_MouseLeave">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeave"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="MouseEnter">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Path.Stroke>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" x:Name="MyAnimatedBrush" />
    </Path.Stroke>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager?view=netframework-4.8), a VisualTransition by itself cannot fire just because the name is "MouseOver".  It still requires an eventhandler of some kind to perform the transition.  You would have to add an eventhandler for the MouseOver event fired by the Path.